# How to do a Sankey Diagram with multiple notes in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, visualization

I want to create a Sankey Diagram that looks like this:

[image: Sankey diagram]

I read the post on [How to Make a Sankey Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166439), but I can't seem to make the right adjustments to get the diagram I want. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I hate to say it, but this instantly reminded me of a post on Reddit I saw yesterday: [My 2 Months on Tinder as a Gay Woman](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/7q8s3r/my_2_months_on_tinder_as_a_gay_woman_oc/).

Comment: I´d like vey much that Mathematica could generate this type os graphs with this style os labels.