# How can I make this pipe network shape?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, code-request

I want to draw this shape in Mathematica. I don't know what to start with. Can I use `BezierCurve`? Or should I try to form an equation that could end up in this shape?

[image]

Comment: Which details are important in this shape? The thickness? The arrows? The red? What format do you need? Are you trying to produce an image? Would it be okay to build a tree or graph and just plot it?

Comment: I think since the user mentioned Bezier curves they would like practically the same image but with the lines straightened and a more symmetric figure that looks as close as possible to the drawing.

Comment: Note that this could be done quickly with inkscape . For example type hand drawn to pattern with inkscape on youtube and you will see a relatively easy tutorial suitable for a beginner.

Comment: If you just want the shape as it is then you can copy paste it and set img=TheImage then `ImageMesh@ColorNegate@img`.

Comment: Yes, use `BezierCurve`, as it essentially allows you to specify the tangent at the endpoints, and you want a vertical tangent at both endpoints and branching points. Please try to make the question a bit more concrete: ideally show what you tried with `BezierCurve`, but at a minimum give some example data that should be used to construct the graphics. How do you represent this tree? When you tagged the question [tag:graphs-and-networks], did you mean to indicate that you are looking to work wit `Graph`? I am asking because this tag is often misused to mean "graphs" = "plots".

Comment: If you are looking to work with `Graph`, it may be useful for you to look at the last example here: http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#drawing-bipartite-graphs It's not the same, but it creates edges with similar shapes and shows how one may define an edge shape using `BezierCurve`.

Comment: You are perhaps looking for a `Dendrogram` with styling.

Comment: The shape resembles a Sankey diagram. Maybe the answers in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/166439/58370) question can help.

Comment: @lericr , the shape is important. Imagine this as a pipe network for water flow. Arrows and others things are not as important as the network itself

Comment: @userrandrand, can't it be done using mathematica? I don't want to use another software just for a diagram

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you for sharing the link. It looks very useful

Comment: if you want to draw a pipe network quickly without focusing on the quality of the output you can also draw lines and curves in mathematica using the drawing tools : https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A spline solution:

```
    Module[{th, rl, ll, pts, join, liquid}, th = 20;
 rl = {{0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 2/3}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 4/3}, {1, 2}};
 ll = {{2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 2/3}, {3/2, 1}, {1, 4/3}, {1, 2}};
 pts = {Flatten[{rl, {1, 3} + # & /@ rl, {2, 6} + # & /@ 
      rl, {{3, 8}}}, 1], ll, 
   Flatten[{{{3, -1}, {3, 0}}, {1, 3} + # & /@ ll}, 1], 
   Flatten[{{{4, -1}, {4, 4}}, {2, 6} + # & /@ ll}, 1]};
 liquid = {{{0, -1}, {0, -.5}}, {{2, -1}, {2, -.5}}, 
{{3, -1}, {3,-.5}}, {{4, -1}, {4, -.5}}};
 Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[th], BSplineCurve /@ pts, White, 
   AbsoluteThickness[th - 1], 
   BSplineCurve /@ Evaluate[pts /. 8 -> 8.02], Black,
   AbsoluteThickness[th], BSplineCurve /@ liquid, Lighter[Red, .75], 
   AbsoluteThickness[th - 1], 
   BSplineCurve /@ Evaluate[liquid /. -.5 -> -.48], Black, 
   AbsoluteThickness[1], Opacity[.25],
   Arrowheads[.075], Dashed, 
   Arrow[BSplineCurve[#]] & /@ {{1, 3} + # & /@ 
      Reverse@Rest@rl, {1, 3} + # & /@ Reverse@Rest@ll, {2, 6} + # & /@
       Reverse@Rest@rl, {2, 6} + # & /@ Reverse@Rest@ll, 
     Reverse@Rest@rl, Reverse@Rest@ll},
   Opacity[1], Dashing[None], Line[{{-.5, -1.21}, {4.5, -1.21}}]
   }
  ]]
```

[image]

This was just built from basic building block:

```
Module[{pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 2/3}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 4/3}, {1, 2}}}, 
 Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. How do you find the points for the BSplineCurve ?

Comment: @userrandrand please see update

Comment: Thanks I am not familiar with constructing curves from BSplineCurve. To get the elementary building block did you use `Manipulate` or is it a well known building block that one can find in a repository of fundamental blocks ? Maybe it's natural from experience I would have to build an intuition around it.

Comment: @userrandrand you can play around with `DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 
     1}}}, LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Dynamic[Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, 
     Point[pts]}]], Appearance -> None]]` to get a feel of it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help . I got a better idea of the main properties such as collinear points stay collinear, the endpoints  do whatever you ask and the middle points follow lazily. I also realized that I could maybe just construct an outline of the figure with `Line` and then maybe `/.Line->BsplineCurve`. Maybe I can use this to smooth pixeled letters for a toy OCR project I have . Thank you again and very neat addition to the figure .

Comment: Thank you very much. You made it look so easy.

Answer (score 14):

**Outline**

- **Gallery**
- **Method 1 : `TreePlot` with `EdgeShapeFunction`**

*straightfoward to use*

- **Method 2: Stack parametric plots**

*Interactive, can be tedious or like a game*

- **Method 3: Nested shifts and line rewiring**

*easy to use black box function with customization*

- **Appendix**

---

#### Gallery

- **Method 1 : `TreePlot` with `EdgeShapeFunction`**

**Note :** There are small imperfections from edge corners near the vertices.

[image]

- **Method 2: Stack parametric plots**

[image]

- **Method 3: Nested shifts and line rewiring**

[image]

---

#### Method 1 : `TreePlot` with `EdgeShapeFunction`

**Drawback** : *The edges can not be extracted without involving image processing and so the inner part of the pipes have to be colored. An explanation of how to obtain the edges via image processing is given in the appendix*.

In the first subsection of the Applications section in the documentation for BezierCurves there is the following edge shape function:

```
bezieredge = 
  Function[{pts}, 
   BezierCurve[{pts[[
      1]], {pts[[1, 1]], (pts[[1, 2]] + 2 pts[[2, 2]])/3}, {pts[[2, 
       1]], (2 pts[[1, 2]] + pts[[2, 2]])/3}, pts[[2]]}]];
```

Thickening the lines, increasing the opacity, adding [`DropShadowing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DropShadowing.html) (new in version 13.1) for some "edge" and including the previous edge shape function (the w labels are arbitrary):

```
TreePlot[
 Tree[w, {Tree[w, {Tree[w, {Tree[w, {w}]}], Tree[w, {Tree[w, {w}]}]}],
     Tree[w, {w}], Tree[w, {w}]}] // TreeGraph, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> bezieredge, 
 EdgeStyle -> 
  Directive[Thickness[0.05], Opacity[1], Black, 
   DropShadowing[{-3, 3}, 5, RGBColor[0.300725, 0.680491, 0.901701]]],
  VertexLabels -> None, VertexShape -> None]
```

---

#### Method 2: Stack parametric plots

**Drawback** : Interactive not algorithmic

The following is an incomplete answer. It is a tedious task of lego packing `Tanh` curves. It could be kind of soothing or amusing to play with but it's not a quick algorithm. Although I did not use `Manipulate` to find the parameters below, a code to use `Manipulate` is provided in the appendix.

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot[{{Tanh[x], x}, {-Tanh[x], x}}, {x, -10, 0}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Orange];

plot2 = ParametricPlot[{{Tanh[x] - 4, x}, {4 - Tanh[x], x}}, {x, -10, 
    3}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Orange];

plot3 = ParametricPlot[{Tanh[x] - 2, x + 13}, {x, -10, 3}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Orange];

  plot4 = ParametricPlot[{2*Tanh[x] + 5, x + 13}, {x, -10, 0}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Orange];

plot5 = ParametricPlot[{5 - 2*Tanh[x], x + 13}, {x, -23, 0}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Orange];

plot6 = ParametricPlot[{10 - Tanh[x], x + 13}, {x, -23, 3}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Orange];

Show[{plot3, plot2, plot1, plot4, plot5, plot6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

#### Method 3: Nested shifts and line rewiring

**Drawback:** the code can only generate nested iterations of the tree structure given in the question.

The plots in the gallery above can be made easily with the code below. As examples:

The straight lines can be obtained with (code definitions below)

```
node // nestAddnode[2] //Graphics
```

where n=2 represents the number of recursions performed by `nestAddnode`. Increasing the number of recursions increases the number of nodes in the graph. Curved lines can be obtained with:

```
node // nestAddnode[2]// ReplaceAll[Line -> BSplineCurve] //Graphics
```

`node` above is a list of lines with the following graphical representation:

[image]

Other types of nodes made of three lines with three openings of equal width might also work if the lines are given as {Line[{pts1}],Line[{pts2}],Line[{pts3}]} with pts a list of points (not segments of points such as {{ptsa,ptsb},{ptsc,ptsd}). The points in the lines also have to be ordered according to the image below:

```
label[label_, point_] := 
  Sequence @@ ({Text[Style[label, Medium], # + 0.2], Point@#} &@
     point);

{node, Red, PointSize@Large, label["start", node[[1, 1, 1]]], 
  label["end", node[[1, 1, -1]]], label["start", node[[2, 1, 1]]], 
  label["end", node[[2, 1, -1]]], label["start", node[[3, 1, 1]]], 
  label["end", node[[3, 1, -1]]]} // Graphics
```

[image]

The method of constructing the tree consists of recursively shifting the node in the image above to the lower left of the tree, rewiring lines to make extended lines rather than line segments and extending vertical lines. The reason for rewiring the lines rather than  keeping segments of lines is that it allows transforming straight lines to curves using a replacement rule like `Line->BSplineCurve` for example.

Other than `BSplineCurve`, the image in the gallery used the following resource functions as options to make curves:

- [ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CurveToBSplineFunction/)
- [ResourceFunction["RoundedLine"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RoundedLine/?i=RoundedLine&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch)
- [ResourceFunction["AkimaSpline"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AkimaSpline/?i=AkimaSpline&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch)

**code**

code to make `node` :

**Note:** …=[Ellipsis]

```
path1 = AnglePath[{Pi/4, -Pi/4, -Pi/4}];
Clear[pt1, pt2];
{pt1, pt2} = {path1[[1]] - {1/2, 0}, path1[[-1]] + {1/2, 0}};
tsol = Min@
   SolveValues[
    Norm[pt1 + \[FormalT]*{Cos[Pi/4], 
         Sin[Pi/4]} - (pt2 + \[FormalT]*{-Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]})] == 
     1/2, \[FormalT], Reals];
vertical…edge…height = {0, 1};
node = {Line[{pt1 - vertical…edge…height, pt1, 
     pt1 + tsol*{Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]}, 
     pt1 + tsol*{Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]} + 
      vertical…edge…height}], 
   Line@Join[{path1[[1]] - vertical…edge…height}, 
     path1, {path1[[-1]] - vertical…edge…height}],
    Line[{pt2 + tsol*{-Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]} + 
      vertical…edge…height, 
     pt2 + tsol*{-Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]}, pt2, 
     pt2 - vertical…edge…height}]};
```

Code that adds `node` to a tree of nodes:

```
Clear[addLeft];

addLeft[tree_,node_]:=
Module[{shifted…node},
shifted…node=
Map[#-First@Extract[tree,{{1,1,-1},{-1,1,1}}]+First@Extract[tree,{{1,1,1},{2,1,1}}]&,
    node,
    {3}]
;

{
Join[shifted…node[[1]],
    tree[[1]],
    2]
,

shifted…node[[2]]
,

Join[Reverse/@shifted…node[[3]],
    tree[[2]],
    Line[{tree[[2,1,-1]],
        tree[[2,1,-1]]+{0,-tree[[2,1,-1,-1]]+shifted…node[[1,1,1,2]]}}
    ]
    ,2]
,

(* extend other columns *)
Sequence@@Table[    
        Join[
        Line[{
            tree[[m,1,1]]+{0,-tree[[m,1,1,-1]]+shifted…node[[1,1,1,-1]]}
            ,
            tree[[m,1,1]]}
        ]
        ,
        tree[[m]]
        ,
        Line[{tree[[m,1,-1]],
            tree[[m,1,-1]]+{0,-tree[[m,1,-1,-1]]+shifted…node[[1,1,1,-1]]}}
        ],
        2],
        {m,3,Length@tree-1}]
,
Join[       
    tree[[-1]]
    ,
    Line[{tree[[-1,1,-1]],
        tree[[-1,1,-1]]+{0,-tree[[-1,1,-1,-1]]+shifted…node[[1,1,1,-1]]}
        }
    ]
,
2]
}
]
```

Nested application of `addLeft` :

```
nestAddnode[n_][node_] := Nest[addLeft[#, node] &, node, n];
```

code to use optional random coloring as in the plots above:

```
Clear[colorize];
colorize := 
  Riffle[Thread@Hue[RandomReal[] + Subdivide[Length@#]], #] &;
```

code to use optional resource function customizations:

```
spline[pts_] := 
 ParametricPlot[ResourceFunction["AkimaSpline"][pts][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Axes -> False]


spline2[pts_, d__] := 
 ParametricPlot[
  ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"][pts, d][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Axes -> False]

showSpline[node_] := 
  node /. Line[s_] :> spline[N@DeleteDuplicates@Simplify@s] // 
   Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &;

showSpline2[node_, d__] := 
  node /. Line[s_] :> spline2[N@DeleteDuplicates@Simplify@s, d] // 
   Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &;

    showSpline3[node_, d__] := 
  node /. Line[s_] :> 
    ResourceFunction["RoundedLine"][N@DeleteDuplicates@Simplify@s, d];
```

The image in the gallery was produced with :

**Note :** Uses resource function `ResourceFunction["NearEqualPartition"]` in code below.

```
node // nestAddnode[2] // {Graphics, 
     ReplaceAll[Line -> BSplineCurve]/*colorize/*Graphics, 
     showSpline, (showSpline3[#, 0.7] &)/*colorize/*Graphics, 
     showSpline2[#, 2, 0.5] &} // Through // 
  ResourceFunction["NearEqualPartition"][#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid
```

#### Appendix

The edges from the treeplot can be obtained via image processing. To increase quality of the final image, the image is also remade into a graphics objects. That last step can lead to errors but it the errors seem minor in the image below:

The plot given above with different parameters :

```
plot=TreePlot[
  Tree[w, {Tree[
      w, {Tree[w, {Tree[w, {w}]}], Tree[w, {Tree[w, {w}]}]}], 
     Tree[w, {w}], Tree[w, {w}]}] // TreeGraph, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> bezieredge, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.1], Opacity[1], Black], 
  VertexLabels -> None, VertexShape -> None];
```

Image from plot:

```
im = Image@plot;
```

obtaining the edge from the branches:

```
im2 = im // ImageData // Part[#, All, All, 4] & // Image // 
MorphologicalPerimeter // Dilation[#, 2] & // ColorNegate
```

Turn the image back to a graphics object:

```
im2 // ImageGraphics;
```

[image: im3]

- **Method 2: Stack parametric plots**

Code to use `Manipulate`

I did not use `Manipulate` to obtain the parameters above I just guessed based on what I expected from scaling and shifting step by step. If you would like a more interactive approach I left a code to use Manipulate below

With the parameter choices below initially the curves are super imposed. I would recommend starting small with just 1 or 2 curves and using some of the parameter choices above.

The curve function. To produce quicker plots I reduced the number of points. You can take default options for the plot once your find the parameter choice.

```
    Clear[plot]; 
plot[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ, 
  f_?NumericQ] := 
 ParametricPlot[{a + b*Tanh[x], c*x + d}, {x, e, f}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotPoints -> 30, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

Ranges for parameters a,b,c,d,e. splice should be undefined and will be used in a replacement rule later. The syntax is splice[min,max] where min and max represent the minimal and maximal value of the parameter:

```
arange = splice[0, 10]; brange = splice[-5, 5]; crange = 
 splice[-2, 2]; drange = splice[0, 15]; erange = splice[-30, 0];
frange = splice[0, 5];
```

The manipulate function (Note that you might need to enlarge the image):

- n below is the number of curves
- the comment below is to keep track of the meaning of the variables on the controllers by giving the plot command for the first curve. The syntax is v[1,1]=a in the expression for plot, v[1,2]=b,v[1,3]=c,v[1,4]=d,v[1,5]=e,v[1,6]=f,v[2,1]=a,v[2,2]=b,etc
- click the plus sign next to each controller to enter values

the code:

```
n = 2;
Manipulate[
 Evaluate@
  Quiet@Show[plot @@@ Array[v, {n, 6}], ImageSize -> Small, 
    PlotRange -> All], 
 Transpose[{#, {arange, brange, crange, drange, erange, frange}}] & /@
       Array[v, {n, 6}] /. splice -> Sequence // Catenate // 
   Apply[Sequence] // Evaluate, DefaultLabelStyle -> Orange, 
 Paneled -> False, ControlPlacement -> Left]

(* {v[1,1]+v[1,2]*Tanh[x],v[1,3]*x+v[1,4]},{x,v[1,5],v[1,6]} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 12):

A couple of years ago, I wrote a (somewhat general) function to make [Sankey diagrams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240804/41179). The top-level function (`parseSankeyAssociation`) doesn't seem to work out of the box for this use-case, but we can achieve a fairly decent result using the `sankeyRibbonGraphics` function defined at the bottom of the answer.

```mathematica
With[{length=10,col=Black,width=2.5},
{
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{0,-3},{0,-2}},{{length,-1},{length,0}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{length,-1},{length,0}},{{2length,-1},{2length,0}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{2length,-1},{2length,0}},{{3length,-1},{3length,0}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{0,-3},{0,-2}},{{length,-5},{length,-4}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{length,-5},{length,-4}},{{2length,-3},{2length,-2}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{length,-5},{length,-4}},{{2length,-7},{2length,-6}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{2length,-3},{2length,-2}},{{3length,-3},{3length,-2}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{2length,-7},{2length,-6}},{{3length,-5},{3length,-4}}},col,width],
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{{2length,-7},{2length,-6}},{{3length,-9},{3length,-8}}},col,width]
}//Graphics
]
```

Note, this uses the excellent answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/vary-the-thickness-of-a-plotted-function/28208#28208) on using `ParametricPlot` to make constant-thickness (or in-fact varying-thickness) ribbons.

[image]

#### Edit:

For self-completeness here's the necessary minified code (Note I swapped the `colDirective` option to affect `BoundaryStyle` instead of `PlotStyle` to get the outlines. See edit history if you prefer the filled output)

```mathematica
thickness[f_,th_]:=Block[{x},{x,f}+Normalize[{-D[f,x],1}] th]
sankeyRibbonFunction[{{sourceMin_,sourceMax_},{targetMin_,targetMax_}},width_:10]:=With[{sourceCentroid=Last@Mean[{sourceMin,sourceMax}],targetCentroid=Last@Mean[{targetMin,targetMax}],midpoint=First@Mean[{sourceMin,targetMin}]},(targetCentroid-sourceCentroid)/(1+E^(-width (-midpoint+x)))+sourceCentroid]
sankeyRibbonGraphics[{{sourceMin_,sourceMax_},{targetMin_,targetMax_}},colDirective_,width_:10]:=With[{heightSource=Last[sourceMax-sourceMin]/2,heightTarget=Last[targetMax-targetMin]/2},First[ParametricPlot[Evaluate@thickness[sankeyRibbonFunction[{{sourceMin,sourceMax},{targetMin,targetMax}},width],If[heightSource==heightTarget,heightSource t,heightSource t+(heightTarget-heightSource) t LogisticSigmoid[width (x-(First[sourceMin]+First[targetMin])/2)]]],{x,First[sourceMin],First[targetMin]},{t,-1,1},PlotPoints->{25,3},MaxRecursion->4,Mesh->None,BoundaryStyle->colDirective,PlotStyle->None]]]
```

Comment: Nice I was able to remove the lines inside the diagram with image processing by defining g to be the diagram and using `ImageMeasurements[FillingTransform[ColorNegate@Image@g], 
  "Contours"] // Graphics` but as expected that introduces pixelization error  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIGQJ.png . Nice function

Comment: `Graphics[MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[...], 1]]` also seems to work reasonably well, where `...` is the filled graphics output using `BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> colDirective` in the `sankeyRibbonGraphics` function

Comment: Oh that's how you get `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` to work. I tried that initially and got an error. Thanks for the nice trick that might come in handy later

Comment: This is wonderful. Truly. I just want to know one more thing. How can I make the branching portion smoother? Would increasing `mech` do the trick?

Comment: Increasing `m` in `PlotPoints->{m,3}` should do it. The second dimension is for the thickness which at-most varies linearly so a low number suffices

Answer (score 10):

Use `Translate` with multiples of `3` along x-axis and multiples of `4` along y-axis to move objects `o1` and `o2`.

```
o1 = {Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
   Circle[{2, 0}, 2, {π + ArcTan[Sqrt[7]/3], π + π/2}], 
   Circle[{2, 0}, 1, {π, π + π/2}], 
   Circle[{2, -3}, 2, {0, 0 + π/2}], 
   Circle[{2, -3}, 1, {0, 0 + π/2}], 
   Circle[{2 - 3, 0}, 
    2, {3/2 π, 3/2 π + π/2 - ArcTan[Sqrt[7]/3]}], 
   Circle[{2 - 3, 0}, 1, {3/2 π, 3/2 π + π/2}], 
   Circle[{2 - 3, -3}, 2, {π/2, π/2 + π/2}], 
   Circle[{2 - 3, -3}, 1, {π/2, π/2 + π/2}]};

o2 = {Line[{{0, 1}, {0, 5}}], Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 5}}]};

Graphics[{o1, Translate[o1, {-3, -4}], Translate[o1, {-6, -8}], 
  Translate[o2, {3, -8}], Translate[o2, {3, -12}], 
  Translate[o2, {0, -12}], Translate[o2, {-9, -16}], 
  Translate[o2, {-3, -16}], Translate[o2, {0, -16}], 
  Translate[o2, {3, -16}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's simple and efficient